# R- How to get locations/positions of elements of a vector that satisfies given conditions?

Tags: r, subset, analysis

I am using R studio with R 3.1.2 on Mac ox X 10.10.3, i need to get positon of elments in a vector when it is given some conditions.

Let x be a sample of 100 elements and y is equals to 100.
How to get a vector stating positions of elements of x, for which  x >y

I have tried functions like match, replace and %in%, but not much success. Either i am missing something oe doing it all wrong.

Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 2):

If you need the first position where `x >y`, try `which.max`

```
which.max(x>y)
#[1] 6
```

It could be also done with `which`

```
 which(x >y)[1]
 #[1] 6
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
x <- sample(1:140, 100, replace=TRUE)
y <- 100
```